# converting string to integer for prepared statment

Tags: java, jdbc, jakarta-ee, javafx, javafx-2

Iam using javafx to update the database using prepardstatement but while running it iam getting this error at the console and doesnt shows while compilation. It looks like the string is not getting the values whatever entered in it. maybe i was wrong still figuring out

```
var input: TextBox;

var inputnum = Integer.parseInt({input.text});


stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into dummy2 values(?,?,?)");
            stmt.setString(1,"");
            stmt.setString(2, "");
            stmt.setInt(3, inputnum);
```

Getting error:-

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:468)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
        at testint.Main$Main$Script.applyDefaults$(Main.fx:36)
        at testint.Main$Main$Script.applyDefaults$(Main.fx:36)
        at testint.Main.javafx$run$(Main.fx)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because string you are trying to parse is `""` which isn't parsable to `int`.

You probably need to validate the input or if you want to allow `""` then assign some default value for such case.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't show at compile-time, no - `input.text` is an empty string (at execution time), and when you try to parse it, that's failing.

You need to work out what you want to do when `input.text` is empty.

Comment: In my javafx code the validation is working properly but if i refer to a variable sending it as args to the resultset am getting illegal forward reference error. For exmple:

Comment: @jbs123: You're really not making yourself clear, I'm afraid.

Comment: @skeet Dont be afraid its just trying it on a new way using javafx and i fixed it on my own Thank you